# How to struture a db to store different types of data?

Tags: database, structure

Apologies if this is an answered question or in the wrong place - pointers welcome.

I’m in the planning stage of a personal project for logging data. The number and types of data fields need to be configurable (from a web interface) which leaves me wondering how best to structure the thing.

One set of column headings (of data to be stored) might look like this

```
Timestamp

Name (string)

Weight (float)
```

Another set of data headings might be

```
Timestamp

Meal (string)

Description (string)
```

I know I could model this like a collection of sheets, columns and data but it doesn’t feel very efficient or best-practicey.

Data structure table Collections (defines sheet name)

```
Collection id

Collection name
```

Columns table (defines sheet colums & data types)

```
Column id

Collection id

Column name

Column data type
```

Data Items table (holds data)

```
Column id

Item data
```

Does this look like the best way to do this? Is there a better way (nosql?). Suggestions / opinions please.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to logging data from your services you can use another a non relational database... like mongodb and you can store a bson with the information you want

Comment: Thanks for the response Fernando. I was hoping for a few more opinions but I think I'll see if it's possible in sql and then look at mongo.

Cheers

Comment: It may be possible to do that, however you will not be 100% of what you need, maybe at the beginning... but if you need to add another type of data? ... any that you have created? ... it will be to modify the structure of your tables, which would not happen with a non-relational bd, not always what we try to use to give the solution is the best way to do it